# How can I add a RSS Feed to the Windows 7 RSS Gadget?

Tags: windows-7, rss, desktop-gadget, sidebar, feed-reader

I use Windows 7 and I can add gadgets to the sidebar. One of the gadget is an [RSS reader](http://video.about.com/windows/How-to-Use-the-RSS-Gadget.htm). How can I add a RSS Feed to it? At the moment I have no feeds. I would like to have one from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should first go to that RSS URL on Internet Explorer and subscribe to that feed. Then you can open the options list of the gadget, select the feed from the dropdown list and view the relevant feeds.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that I had to use Internet Explorer.

Comment: Or you can use firefox

Answer (score 1):

Now that the Gallery has been retired, an alternative to the "Feed Headlines" RSS gadget is the [Hermes](http://hermesgadget.codeplex.com) RSS reader gadget (note: I am affiliated with this project). This reader is an enhanced version (of Feed Headlines - which was no longer being updated) and is free, and is also used (by some) within MS. It can be used without IE or with it.

Comment: Will do if possible :)

Answer (score 0):

i found a tutorial to how to get it working (i.. think?)  here it is! https://www.wikihow.tech/Subscribe-to-and-Read-RSS-Feeds-with-Internet-Explorer

if its working have fun :D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).